# jenkins pipeline sh adding new line

Tags: jenkins, groovy, sh, jenkins-pipeline, terraform

My pipeline sh block:

```
 sh "set +e; /terraform/terraform plan -var aws_access_key=${aws_access_key} -
 var aws_secret_key=${aws_secret_key} -var aws_ami=${ami_id} -var 
 aws_instance_type=${instance_type} -var aws_elb_security_group=${elb_sg} -var 
 aws_ec2_security_group=${ec2_sg} -detailed-exitcode; echo \$? > status"
              exitCode = readFile('status').trim()
              echo "Terraform Plan Exit Code: ${exitCode}"
```

output :

```
+ set +e
+ /terraform/terraform plan -var aws_access_key=**** -var aws_secret_key=**** -var aws_ami=ami-xxxxxxx
+ -var aws_instance_type=t2.medium -var aws_elb_security_group=sg-xxxx
/terraform/selectdev/int/mp-frontend@tmp/durable-6c57c14c/script.sh: line 3: -var: command not found
+ -var aws_ec2_security_group=sg-axxx
 /terraform/selectdev/int/mp-frontend@tmp/durable-6c57c14c/script.sh: line 4: -var: command not found
+ -detailed-exitcode
/terraform/selectdev/int/mp-frontend@tmp/durable-6c57c14c/script.sh: line 5: 
 -detailed-exitcode: command not found
+ echo 127
```

I'm not sure why new line is being added to the command and If I do single quotes like sh '', variables are blank. what am I doing wrong ?

I tried to do like below but it too adding new lines

```
def command = $/....../$
res = sh(returnStdout: true, script: command)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The variables I'm using are from other stages and have new line.. had to use .trim()

Comment: Specific example:

```script {
                MY_FILE_ID = sh( returnStdout: true, script: 'uuidgen').trim()
            }```

Because without ```.trim()``` the variable has a newline at the end of it.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe I never thought of this...

Answer (score 19):

First, FYI: [single quotes skip variable interpolation in groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_single_quoted_string)

If you want to have a multiple line script in a string, you need to escape endlines in a multi line variable.

You need three things:

1. [Use triple double strings](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_triple_double_quoted_string) `"""`. This allows you to have multi-line strings with interpolation (triple single quoted strings `'''` let you do the same thing without interpolation).
2. Escape endlines with `\`. This lets you insert newlines to format a long command.
3. Wrap variables with double quotes (valid within triple double quotes, but you can also just escape the double quotes otherwise: `\"`)

For example as follows: (one argument per line for readability)

```
sh("""set +e; /terraform/terraform plan \
-var aws_access_key="${aws_access_key}" \
-var aws_secret_key="${aws_secret_key}" \
-var aws_ami="${ami_id}" \
-var aws_instance_type="${instance_type}" \
-var aws_elb_security_group="${elb_sg}" \
-var aws_ec2_security_group="${ec2_sg}" \
-detailed-exitcode; echo \$? > status""")
```